# Moodle Outgoing Mail Server Configuration not working

Tags: moodle

We've been using Moodle 3.8 in which we want to send notifications to Users through Emails. For that we have configured Office365 Mailing Server as per Moodle Documentation. But while testing configuration through test mail feature, it returns with an error saying,
**Your site couldn't communicate with your mail server. Please check your outgoing mail configuration.**

Moodle Version - 3.8.3

SMTP Server - Office365

Note:- Website has sub-domain of a registered domain of Organization.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hi there! A couple questions for you:

What are the settings you are currently using in your Moodle's outgoing mail configuration for the following:   
* SMTP host   
* SMTP security  
* SMTP Auth type  
    
(Note: feel free to redact accordingly if you are using an mx record of your own domain as the SMTP host and would rather keep that information private).

Comment: I also have the same issue using Gmail. My setting is the following: SMTP Host: smtp.gmail.com:465    SMTP Security: SSL     SMTP Auth Type: LOGIN    SMTP username: myownemail@gmail.com SMTP password: mypassword. While testing the configuration I also received the same error.

Comment: I tried using the same configuration but this time is from my local server (my macbook, using MAMP). I tested using my gmail account, and non gmail account. They both worked perfectly. So, I am puzzled why it doesn't work from my web hosting (awardspace) using the same configuration. I compared the php version and the one in my web hosting is more updated version.

Answer (score 4):

Please add `:587` in the SMTP hosts it works so it will be

SMTP hosts - `smtp.gmail.com:587`

SMTP security  - `TLS`